# Does wget -O overrides the argument -N?

Tags: wget

I want to download a file `A.bmp` and it needs to be renamed to `myA.bmp` The download should only happens if the file on the server is newer than my local version. So I tried the following command:

```
wget -N -O ./dumps/myA.bmp http://webserver.org/bmp/A.bmp
```

This will indeed download the file on the first try. But if I execute the command a second time e.g. two minutes after the file will be downloaded again.

I tried another cli argument to download file. This time I used the option `-P` which will download the file `A.bmp` into a directory.

```
wget -N -P ./dumps http://webserver.org/bmp/A.bmp
```

This works as suggested. The file is downloaded only once until the timestamp of the file on the server is newer. But unfortunately the file isn't renamed to `myA.bmp` as you can image.

Why doesn't behave `wget -O -N` like the `-N -P` version? Is it possible the `-O` overrides the `-N` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `man` page for `wget`:

Under the section for `Download Options`, `-O file`:

> For this reason, -N (for timestamp-checking) is not supported in
> combination with -O: since file is always newly created, it will
> always have a very new timestamp. A warning will be issued if this

Comment: I'm so sorry. I missed that cause I never checked the `man`. I only read the `--help` output and I have expected some kind of hint for the `-O -N` combination. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have nothing to apologize for. Don't be afraid of the `man`.